# .NET MAUI Shell - Show Hamburger icon after navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I have a couple of questions regarding showing the Hamburger icon which shows the Flyout and going to the previous page.

I Created the default app in Visual Studio and added a second page

[image]

I registered the second page in AppShell.xaml.cs

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SecondPage), typeof(SecondPage));
```

In MainPage.xaml, I added a button which when pressed sends the user to the second page

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SecondPage), true);
```

This all works.
But, while on the first page we can see the Hamburger icon
[image]

When arriving on the second page from the button click, we see a back button and no hamburger icon

[image]

You can still swipe from the left to show the Flyout but
**How do I show the hamburger icon on the second page?**

My second question is if I add a link to the second page in the Flyout - AppShell.xaml

```
<ShellContent
        Title="Second Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SecondPage}"
        Route="SecondPage" />
```

When it is clicked then we DO see the hamburger icon

[image]

but no back button and if you click back using Android's Back button then it exits the App. So, my second quesiont is **How do I make a click on the menu behave like the button being clicked.**

Comment: May I know exactly what you want to achieve . You may want hamburger icon or Android's back button on secondpage, or both?

Comment: For the first question the hamburger is replaced with back button because the page reacts as a navigation page instead of shell content page. As for second question you cannot go back on shell content because it's a single page and not a navigation page which changes the view based on the same page based on the content.

Comment: @HongxinSui I basically want to always show the hamburger icon on the second page and always want to go back to previous page from it

Comment: @SashiKumar, If I can slide the menu out on the second page, why can't I show a hamburger icon to open the menu? MainPage.xaml and SecondPage.xaml are the same type of page. What do you mean that one is a shell content page and the other is navigation page? where is this set? (or perhaps give me a link where this is explained in detail)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation. This link will be helpful.

Comment: May you consider adding a separate button on SecondPage to return?

Comment: Your second page is a relativel route, it is on top of your root page in the navigation stack. If you don't want this, you need to modify your code so that the root page gets replaced instead of adding it on top of the other page. This is expected behavior in Shell.

Answer (score 6):

That's because the flyout does absolute routing but your code does relative routing and maintains the navigation stack.

If you want to programmatically get the same behavior, you need to switch to absolute routing.

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SecondPage)}");`

Read more about Shell navigation in [the. NET MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation)

Comment: The documentation doesn't explain this. If absolute routing is not possible (e.g. global routes within a flyout page) then there seems to be no way to change this behaviour.

Comment: System.Exception: 'Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: SecondPage' ... so this solution does not work.

Comment: I found that to do correct navigation that preserves the hamburger menu I had to not do the Routing.RegisterRoute() thing, and instead just inside AppShell.xaml on the ShellContent element add Route="SecondPage" then await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//SecondPage"); will navigate using the structure defined in AppShell.xaml

Answer (score -1):

try sliding your finger to the right when you navigate to the second page through button